# multiple custom request header entries using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to have multiple custom request header entries for my httpclient object before I send the request.  The Request I want to send should look like this:

```
Request Headers     
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:213
Content-Type:application/json     
Host:portal.idtbeyond.com
Origin:https://portal.idtbeyond.com
Referer:https://portal.idtbeyond.com/activedocs
x-idt-beyond-app-id:xxccccxx
x-idt-beyond-app-key:yyuuuttttddfdfdfdfdfd
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
view parsed
{
   "country_code": "SV",
   "carrier_code": "Claro",
   "mobile_number": "50363751234",
   "plan": "Sandbox",
   "amount": "500",
   "client_transaction_id": "",
   "terminal_id": "KIOSK 1",
   "origin_country": "US"
}
```

The Code I am writing in C# is as below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_ProviderService.GatewayUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new  MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-idt-beyond-app-id",
       _PayingMerchant.Username);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-idt-beyond-app-key", 
       _PayingMerchant.Password);
    var urlSuffix = GetUrlSuffix(trans);                  

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlSuffix).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            TopUpResponse topUpResponse = 
               response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TopUpResponse>().Result;
            if (topUpResponse.success)
            {
                result.Success = true;
                result.ReturnValue = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting a 404 response and debugging shows that the header section is wrong on my part.  I am new to these requests and would appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: 404 usually indicates the specific service you are trying to pass to doesn't exist; if it were an issue with a header, a 400 bad request or alternative error is usually returned...  Are you sure the 404 is returned because of the header?

Comment: Thanks for the replies,  the issue I'm having is the multiple headers,  when I look at my network - the X-idt params are appended to the Accepts section of the headers.  Commenting out the two x-idt params returns a not authorised response from the gateway. I've verified the gateway url and its correct

Answer (score 0):

Try setting referer as well as follows:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referer = https://portal.idtbeyond.com/activedocs
```

And make sure you are using correct GatewayUrl

Comment: Thanks for the replies, the issue I'm having is the multiple headers, when I look at my network - the X-idt params are appended to the Accepts section of the headers. Commenting out the two x-idt params returns a not authorised response from the gateway. I've verified the gateway url and its correct